# enabling WCDMA on galaxy s2 I9100

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, cdma

We have 2 WCDMA networks here in IRAQ but SGS2 I9100 cannot find any of them even when I'm choosing WCDMA mode from network operators, while it works fine with GSM.  Why?

Comment: The "Why" question is hard to answer, and rather falls into the off-topic area of *Speculative questions* (see our [FAQ]). Is it really the "Why" you are interested in -- or rather the "How to make it work"?

Answer (score 0):

There are different [WCDMA(UMTS) frequency bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMTS_frequency_bands). I believe that they use Band-I (2100MHz) in IRAQ. You did not mention which country you bought your phone in. But if it was anywhere in North America - I have bad news for you: none of american carriers use this band so very few phones sold here support it.

Comment: thank you very much for the info.i bought my device here in Iraq.So if the Band is (2100MHz) why cant my sgs2 feel it ?